# Python: regex on big file. Easy way?

Tags: python, regex, file, io

I need to run a regex match over a file, but I'm faced with an unexpected problem: the file is too big to `read()` or `mmap()` in one call, File objects don't support the `buffer()` interface, and the regex module takes only strings or buffers.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Does the regex need to match multiple lines, or can you do the equivalent of grep?

Comment: Big. It would need to match multiple lines. I'm taking a different approach now (not a life or death situation), but I was wondering, isn't there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: "Big" is not an answer to my question. The reason I ask, is that if you're on a 64-bit OS (and you should be if you're dealing with "big" files today), then you *will* be able to `mmap()` the file. I've done this with files up to 30 GB, in Python, and it works great.

Comment: @Greg Oh, look at that. No, the file won't get that big :) I'll `mmap()` it. Post it as an answer (maybe provide some code in case someone else stumbles upon this) and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Python [`mmap`](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) module provides a nice Python-friendly way of memory mapping a file. On a 32-bit operating system, the maximum size of the file is will be limited to no more than a GB or maybe two, but on a 64-bit OS you will be able to memory map a file of arbitrary size (until storage sizes exceed 2<sup>64</sup>, of course).

I've done this with files of up to 30 GB (the Wikipedia XML dump file) in Python with excellent results.